# Icon to Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, icons, navigation-drawer

I am trying to add icons to my Navigation Drawer in Android. I have the following code in my main

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    private myAdapter MyAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = {"Math", "Physics", "Chemistry"};

        MyAdapter = new myAdapter(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(MyAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    switch(position) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MathActivity.class);
                            startActivity(a);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhysicsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(b);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Intent c = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChemistryActivity.class);
                            startActivity(c);
                            break;
                        default:
                    }

            }

        });


    }







    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        String SchoolCategories[];
        int[] images = {R.drawable.math_icon,R.drawable.physics_icon,R.drawable.chemistry_icon};

        public myAdapter(Context context){
            this.context = context;
            SchoolCategories = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.school);

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return SchoolCategories.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return SchoolCategories[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = null;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
            }
            else{
                    row =convertView;
            }

            TextView titleTextView =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewRow1);
            ImageView titleImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewRow1);
            titleTextView.setText(SchoolCategories[position]);
            titleImageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return row;
        }
    }
}
```

And the following XML Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/math_icon"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewRow1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewRow1"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

I am simple just trying to add icons to the navigation drawer, but this does not work and I am not sure what goes wrong. The application just shuts down. All help is really appreciated!

Here is my log-cat:

```
05-25 12:27:33.053    3909-3909/oscarorellana.nowwetryitmyway.physicsproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: oscarorellana.nowwetryitmyway.physicsproject, PID: 3909
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {oscarorellana.nowwetryitmyway.physicsproject/oscarorellana.nowwetryitmyway.physicsproject.MathActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
            at oscarorellana.nowwetryitmyway.physicsproject.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:57)
```

Comment: In your Adapter's `getView()` method, you never initialize `row` if `convertView == null`, but then you call `row.findViewById()`, which will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank Mike M! How would this be fixed?? And Eugene H. Log-cat is now posted.

Comment: From your logcat, it seems that you've named your Activity `MathActivity` in the manifest, but the code you've posted has it as `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to declare:
               row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
In myAdapter. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with changing this line:

```
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
```

To this line:

```
       row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
```